# Using Localstorage as fallback when using Angular

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am working on an Angular SPA and have been given the task to save data to local storage if there is no Internet connection. And then the connection is available to then save the data

I see how to use Local Storage but have not come across anything like I describe above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [offline.js](https://github.com/hubspot/offline). You can bind functions to the event of the connection going offline or online and work with that (there are other features, just check it out).

GL & HF.

Comment: Thanks for this link. It is helpful for determining status.  What we are looking for is something that will allow the user to continue to use the application while disconnected - The work they do often takes them out of range while they are filling checklists on Equipment. They need to be able to traverse different views (since Angular downloads these views and scripts on start up, the problem comes in when they attempt to save and continue to the next view.

Comment: Knowing the connection status you can easily set up a service or filter that handles the situation accordingly.

Comment: How would this be accomplished - is there guidance as to how to set up such a service/filter?